# What does 'Something has got to give' mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I have heard this many times, with variations like "something's gotta give", but what exactly does it mean?

Comment: This kind of question is perfect for a search engine like Google. Before asking this kind of General Reference question, please search for the answer yourself: [link](http://dictionary.reference.com/slang/something's+got+to+give)

Comment: @BillFranke, a search engine like google spits out tons of links, each with its own version of the answer. I asked here because the site allows a discussion unlike the search engine.

Comment: @Bill Franke: This is difficult to find on Google because the expression is used in titles of many works, and they really hide the definition of the expression well.

Comment: Click on the link I provided. It's defined in Dictionary.com's slang dictionary. I got that as hit #5 on the first page of my Google search. By the way, I didn't vote to close the question, but I agree that it should be closed.

Comment: [Something](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/something), [has got](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have?q=has#have__18), [to give](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/give?q=give#give__32).

Comment: rob: I agree, search engines don't always provide the most enlightening links, and don't allow discussions, either. But let me give you a tip for asking gen ref questions on ELU: before you ask here, make an earnest effort to figure out the answer. Check Google & OneLook. If that fails, then feel free to ask here, but be sure to include the fruits of your research. Explain (1) where you looked, (2) what you found, and (3) why you're still confused. That formula won't ensure your question will stay open, but it sure has a much better chance if you put forth that effort, and share those results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Macmillan Dictionary entry for [*give*:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/give#give_66)

> If something that supports or holds something *gives*, it breaks.

"Something's gotta give" means that things are building up and the speaker expects that whatever is supporting everything is going to break under the pressure. This can be (and often is) used figuratively.

Comment: '... *elasticity* , and *resilience*, which informally is called *give*' -- What gives? :) You are contradicting yourself here. *Elasticity* is the ability **not** to 'give'; *resilience* gives a bit and returns to state. *Failure* corresponds to the sense you have used 'give'.

Comment: @Kris, Edited to remove that sentence. It was correct, but maybe not clear, and not worth elaborating on. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/give_6