# “something needs to give” vs "something needs to give up"

Tags: word-choice

To quote from The New York Times article "[There’s a Better Way to Reclaim Your Time Than ‘Quiet Quitting’](https://cn.nytimes.com/opinion/20220921/burnout-quiet-quitting/dual/) "

> When you’re exhausted and overwhelmed, it feels like **something needs
> to give** — and for many, that seems to be the pursuit of excellence at
> work.

Here the words **something needs to give** clearly means when you are exhausted you give up (or let go) something, so why did the article  write *it feels like something needs to give*? I looked it up from longman, https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/give but I can't find a clear example for that.

I found a similar question asked and answer here [What does 'Something has got to give' mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87320/what-does-something-has-got-to-give-mean) but I feel that did not answer my question.

> If something that supports or holds something gives, it **breaks**... This
> can be (and often is) used figuratively.

BTW, I attached the dual version of the article because the English version is not free.

Comment: Have you looked up the idiom in dictionaries?

Comment: Yes but I can't find a clear example of show this usage, e.g. https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/give

Comment: Look up the whole idiom, I found it very [easily](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/something%20has%20%28got%29%20to%20give#:~:text=%E2%80%94used%20to%20say%20that%20someone,has%20(got)%20to%20give!).

Comment: 'Give' is here the sense [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give) lists as verb [intransitive] 2a. But it's probably far more common in the fixed expression fev links to. 'Needs' is an alternative in the 'fixed' expression. // Longman senses 27/28.

Comment: So i it more like American English ?

Comment: There's a difference between *something needs to give* and *someone needs to give up*: one is about an inanimate thing, the other about a person.

Comment: This sense of _give_ is the same as the sense of _give out_. I.e, _The water pump gave out, and took the timing belt with it_. It means 'break, fracture, collapse, stop functioning', and the _out_ is not necessary in context -- _I think if you press down here, this piece will give, and you can open it_.

Comment: If you are exhausted and overwhelmed, pursuit of excellence will just make your situation worse. So you are misusing the idiom

Answer (score 3):

"Give" could be used here in the sense of "give out" (which is very closely related to "give up" - saying "the water pump gave out" is virtually the same as saying "the water pump gave up").

But in my opinion it really means "give" in the sense of: ["alter in shape under pressure rather than resist or break."](https://www.google.com/search?q=give%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA753CA753&oq=give%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.1916j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). For example

> the chair gave a little when the heavy person sat on it.

Similarly

> The stuck door gave when the team leaned on it

may mean that the door was broken open, but may also mean it just opened under pressure.

I base this opinion on the fact that when saying that work "gives" it doesn't mean they stop doing it, or even stop doing it well, it just means that they don't devote  the same effort to it that they used to. The "shape" of work alters to reflect the pressure on time and energy.

The general usage is the same "something has got to give" means that there needs to be some flexibility - some "give" - in some aspect of the issue.

Comment: I found a similar question asked before https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87320/what-does-something-has-got-to-give-mean

Answer (score 0):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> This sense of *give* is the same as the sense of *give out*. I.e, *The water pump gave out, and took the timing belt with it*. It means 'break, fracture, collapse, stop functioning', and the *out* is not necessary in context -- *I think if you press down here, this piece will give, and you can open it*.